# Import CSV to SQL - Date format issues: Zeroes

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, import

I'm trying to import CSV data into MySQL database.  I have four `Date` fields. when the import finishes, all my dates are zeroes: [image].

I've set the date format to `DATE` in Excel prior to saving it as `CSV`. I've set the table field as `DATE` in MySQL.

I'm using phpMyAdmin to do the import.

Comment: What input looks like? What command do you use tp import data?

Comment: You have to show us a bit more...

Comment: Date format mismatch results in 000... have a look at format.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql only excepts dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

The Date format in excel is 06/09/2015. Thus, not in the format that mysql is expecting. You must change this to a format that is accepted in mysql otherwise all your date fields will appear as `0000-00-00`.

In order to change the date format in excel: right click on the top cell. Choose `format cells` from the drop down list. change the `local` to something like `'Afrikans'`. Choose the format that looks like `2001-03-14`. Use the top cell to `fill down`. Then save the document.

Just a quick note: Excel sometimes tries to do too much and will revert this column back to a the `English(U.S)` default time zone. So, if you plan on doing more editing make sure that the column has not reverted back.

Here is a link to more string literals on [dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Comment: OK, That did it. Thanks very much.  I set the date columns in Excel to Custom and set format to YYYY-MM-DD as I didn't have an option to change location to non US.  Thanks much! I knew it would be simple.

Comment: If i Helped and answered your questions, please upvote and check as the answer on the left hand side of the QU...Thanks!